# What is the benefit/usage of TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactionscope

I have been using NHibernate for a while and came across the code below that uses a `Transaction scope`.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
       using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
       {
         // do work
       }
     }
}
```

I generally do everyting without wrapping the code to a `TransactionScope` Am I doing something wrong or am I just missing out some beautiful functionality ?

Comment: Look at MSDN documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In the sample shown, btw, the transaction will actually rollback at the end - nothing will get saved to the database. Transactions need to be *committed* (`scope.Complete()`, IIRC)

Answer (score 4):

The *usage* is: transactions. Whether that is *benefit* is more complex. There are *more direct* ways of achieving transactions - ADO.NET transactions. These are a little awkward to work with (you need to remember to set the transaction on every command), but are very efficient.

Transaction scope has the advantage of an *ambient* transaction; this makes it easier to work with. However, it works in a different way. In particular, transaction-scope supports *multiple resource* transactions - which can mean multiple databases etc. This is typically done via DTC, but DTC **has overheads** - it is more expensive (and requires specific firewall configuration, etc). In many single-database cases it can short-cut and use the LTM instead of full DTC, but this is *still* more expensive than ADO.NET transactions... just *not as expensive as DTC*.

A powerful feature, but make sure you *intend* to use it before you do ;p

Comment: Just a note to add that the awkwardness regarding setting transactions for every command doesn't really apply when using NHibernate, since typically you will never handle the IDbCommand directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any TransactionScope explicitly, every statement you execute on the database will run in a separate transaction.

With a TransactionScope you can bundle multiple statements into a big transaction and undo everything as a block.

This is necessary, when updating multiple tables in multiple statements but performing virtually one big thing, that has to work or not be done at all.

Comment: No, TransactionScope is just one way of doing transactions. Depending on usecase, it is perfectly valid to use NHibernate's own transactions (i.e. regular ADO.NET transactions) instead of System.Transactions.Transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing out on some beautiful functionality: with the transaction scope in place, the code with the transaction scope will participate in ambient transaction if invoked from inside a piece of code running in its own transaction scope. Without transaction scope, your code will have its own transaction (from the deepest nested block) which could fail without failing the outer transaction.

In addition, anything inside your `// do work` block would have easier time participating in your transaction if you put a transaction scope outside it. The code would be able to break your transaction without having to propagate the error code up the chain or throwing an exception, which could potentially be ignored by code in the middle.

Note: Don't forget to call `scope.Complete()` on the transaction scope before the end of its `using` block.

Comment: What if I have two transactions inside the transaction scope and while one commits successfully the other one throws an exception. Will the other successfull one be rolled back ?

Comment: @Cemre If you make a nested transaction that commits (as opposed to simply reporting completion) there would be no rollback. Normally, though, this shouldn't happen: each scope that attaches to the ambient transaction would report completion without committing. The command to actually commit would be sent to all participants only at the successful completion of the outermost transaction scope.

Comment: @Cemre Regarding nesting transactions, a transaction nested inside another will typically _NOT_ commit, as seen by the SQL server. The correct use is to call commit on the NHibernate transaction before it goes out of scope, to ensure it has flushed any changes to the database. However, the actual transaction inside the SQL server will still remain uncommitted until the TransactionScope is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using transactions at all.  If you aren't, then you should be.

I personally don't use TransactionScope in any of my NHibernate, but then again I don't need it.  In a web environment with a single database, it's not really necessary. my unit of work is a web request.  I open my connection on BeginRequest and close it on EndRequest.  I use a generic repository that will start a transation if none is present and defined a TransactionAttribute that decorates controller actions so that all table updates are performed in a single transaction.

TransactionScope is just Microsoft's generic way to put all transactional aware resources into a single transaction.  This may be multiple databases, a transactional file system, ....  Things to worry about in these scenarios is that the transaction most likely will be promoted to the DTC to coordinate all the updates.

Also, I don't know if it's still an issue, but older versions of NHibernate used to have a memory leak associated with using TransactionScope.

Here's a link with everything you need to know about TransactionScopes http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope